# How to show/hide divs based on selection using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I'd like to display a different set of text based on a user's selection.  As I'm new to jQuery, I wanted to see if there is a cleaner way to write this out?  My current code is functioning fine, but would love any input on other functions that could accomplish this more quickly before I move further.  Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Select:</label>
    <select class="toggle_div" />
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="group_a"> 
   Text A
</div>

<div id="group_b">
   Text B
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#group_a').hide();
    $('#group_b').hide();

    $('.toggle_div').on('change',function(){

        if($(this).val() == "a"){
            $('#group_a').show();
            $('#group_b').hide();
        }

        if($(this).val() == "b"){
            $('#group_a').hide;
            $('#group_b').show();
        }

        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $('#group_a').hide();
            $('#group_b').hide();
        }       

    })  

});
```

Comment: This is quite fine. Add `else if` instead of just `if` to avoid checking each case. Save reference of $('#group_a') and $('#group_b') for a tiny improve in performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('#group_a').toggle($(this).val() == 'a');
$('#group_b').toggle($(this).val() == 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

One tweak I would suggest is getting the value from the beginning:

```
$val = jQuery(this).val();
```

And then check the value of $val instead of $(this).  So that your code doesn't have to keep resolving $(this).

You could also establish references to your other divs:

```
$groupA = jQuery('#group_a');
$groupB = jQuery('#group_b');
```

Because everytime you use $(selector), you create a new jQuery object that has to be resolved.

You could create $groupA and $groupB outside of your function, so they'd be defined only once for the life of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ids whenever possible, they're more flexible. In your case, using multiple classes would lead to :

```
<div class="group_a hidable"> 
   Text A
</div>

<div class="group_b hidable">
   Text B
</div>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hidable').hide();
    $('.toggle_div').on('change',function(){
        $('.hidable').hide();
        $('.group_'+$(this).val()).show();
    })  
});
```

Comment: I would amend your solution (which is a good one) to use both IDs and a class.  If you want to select only one, specific element, then an ID should be used to identify it.  So the hidable class is good, but group_a and group_b should remain as IDs.

Comment: @solendil the issue with using classes is that they are slower for doing lookup than ids ([link](http://encosia.com/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/)), and he said that he wanted something that would run more quickly.

Comment: I would say two things: 1) don't optimize 2) don't optimize (yet). So you're right, ids are faster than classes, but if it's really a problem, usage of jQuery might also be slower than native JS...

Comment: I agree with you.  I just assumed he wanted it optimized, since he said he wanted something "...that could accomplish this more quickly"

Answer (score 0):

If I was in a terse mood, I might do something like:

```
$('.toggle_div').on('change',function(){
    $('#group_a').hide();
    $('#group_b').hide();

    if($(this).val() == "a")
        $('#group_a').show();

    if($(this).val() == "b")
        $('#group_b').show();   

})
```

But I don't think its a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements to be shown or hidden are all at the same level of the DOM, you can use `.siblings()` to find all of the ones that *aren't* the one of interest.

Also, use a `class` to restrict all actions to the divs that are supposed to be toggled.

```
$('.toggle_div').on('change',function() {

    var which = $(this).val();
    var cls = '.myclass';

    if (which) {
        var sel = '#group_' + which;
        $(sel).show().siblings(cls).hide();
    } else {
        $(cls).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('.toggle_div').on('change', function() {
    $('div[id^="group"]').hide();
    $('#group_' + $(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/R5KSq/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.toggle_div').on('change',function(){
    $('#group_a,#group_a').hide();
    $('#group_' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

You can use selectors to your advantage `$('#group_' + $(this).val())` will be empty if `$(this).val()` is not `a` or `b`, then the selector will be empty and nothing will be shown.
If it is `a`, `#group_a` is selected and shown.
If it is `b`, `#group_b` is selected and shown.

I'd use the event argument and the target rather than `this`, it makes writing these handlers as anonymous functions easier if they are to be reused:

```
$('.toggle_div').on('change',function(event){
    $('#group_a,#group_a').hide();
    $('#group_' + $(event.target).val()).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the value to the div id - hold all the div's in one container and on each change go over them with a loop(each) and check if the val == id show else hide.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is wrap all group_CHAR elements in a main div, add css to hide all group_CHAR elements initially (much faster), and use this js:

```
var g = $('#groups');

$('.toggle_div').on('change',function(){

    $('div', g).hide();

    var t = $(this).val();    
    if (t !== '') {    
        $('#group_' + t, g).show();           
    }
});
```

I've created http://jsfiddle.net/kDGNG/ so you can see it in action.